# Determine if string array or array of strings Grails

Tags: java, arrays, string, grails

I am trying to figure out if an array I have, has more than one string associated with it or if it is just a character array (string). Right now if I enter a singular ID of 1234 I will get an array of 1,2,3,4 but if I say there are two ID's 12 and 34 the array will return 12, 34. How would I check for a string when it should always be an array of strings?

```
<div class="area">
<h2>Select all people who will be Traveling</h2>
<div>
<g:if test="${disabled=='false'}">
 <g:select name="selector" class="claim" value="None" from="${fullList}" optionKey="studentID" optionValue="${{it.firstName + ' ' + it.lastName}}" noSelection="${['null':' ']}" disabled="${disabled}"/>
   <g:if test="${tripInstance?.student!= null }">
   <g:each var="i" in="${(0..<tripInstance?.student?.length) }">
    <div>
     <input class='field' name='Name' readonly type='text' value='${fullList.firstName[(tripInstance?.student[i]).toInteger()]} ${fullList.lastName[(tripInstance?.student[i]).toInteger()]}'/>
     <input class='field' name='student' readonly type='hidden' value='${tripInstance?.student[i]}'/>
       <label class='removeEdit fakeLink'> Remove</label>
    </div>
   </g:each>
   </g:if>
</g:if>

<g:if test="${disabled=='true'}">
<g:if test="${tripInstance?.student!= null }">
 <g:each var="i" in="${(0..<tripInstance?.student?.size()) }">
  <div>
   <input class='field' name='student' readonly disabled="${disabled}" type='text' value='${tripInstance?.student[i]}'/>
  </div>
 </g:each>
 </g:if>
</g:if>
</div>
</div>
```

I have attempted to check based on class. I can't check based on size as a string will have a size and so will an array of strings. It is a string array instead of Int array due to other parts of the code wanting it in this format. Hopefully I'm not overlooking something easy.

Comment: Could it not be `1, 234` or `123, 4` or `1,2,34` or `12,3,4`? Basically, how do you determine the valid states?

Comment: It could be a student of ID of 1 and 234 but the array would register that those are two separate elements, however if only one student ID of 91 or 123 or even 4 (any number of digits but only a single entry) the array will become a character array and split that one entry into multiple elements

Comment: Yes, but how do you disambiguate? You say "the array"... what array?

Comment: tripInstance?.student is a string[] of ID's that were displayed from the list fullList and selected by the user. but if only one ID is selected by the user tripInstance?.student becomes a character array where any double digit or higher number becomes multiple elements instead of a singular element. Beyond that I am not sure how else to describe the issue sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails provides a convenience method on the `params` object to always return a List, rather than possibly iterating over a single String. It is conveniently called `list()`:

```
def ids = params.list('ids')
```

It can be found in the documentation under [Simple Type Converters](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#typeConverters).